# gcc warning when casting "`unsigned` bitset" to `unsigned`; is it still safe?

Tags: c, gcc, casting, unsigned, bitset

For debugging purposes I did cast an "`unsigned` bitset" type to `unsigned`:

The "`unsigned` bitset" looks like this:

```c
typedef struct {
        unsigned f1 : 1;
        unsigned f2 : 1;
        unsigned f3 : 1;
/* ...less than 10 alltogether... */
} output_flags_t
```

And the output code looks like this:

```c
output_flags_t output_flags;
/*...*/
printf("... %u\n", *(const unsigned *) &output_flags);
```

(`gcc` wouldn't like a direct cast)

However when using `-O2` I get an additional warning (gcc 4.8.5):

```text
warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
```

I wonder:
If "`unsigned` bitset" and `unsigned` have the same number of bits; shouldn't the warning be meaningless?
That is:
Isn't that warning only relevant if the sizes of both types are different?

Is there a cleaner way to print the value of an "`unsigned` bitset"?

Comment: I think it said "type-punned"

Comment: You can use a union, but all these stuff around bit-fields is implementation-defined.

Comment: @stark Correct, I had just copied the message from one screen to another, making a mistake. Corrected now.

Comment: @thebusybee `gcc` implementation of bitfields is very well defined :)

Comment: The error isn't about the conversion, it doesn't like two different pointer types for the same variable. If you called a function with both pointers that made changes to a pointee that could have unexpected behavior

Comment: @0___________ *gcc implementation of bitfields is very well defined* [No they are not](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.4.0/gcc/Structures-unions-enumerations-and-bit-fields-implementation.html#Structures-unions-enumerations-and-bit-fields-implementation).  "Defined by the ABI" is pretty much a synonym for "not portable".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be cleaner to use a `union`:

```
typedef union {
    struct {
        unsigned f1 : 1;
        unsigned f2 : 1;
        unsigned f3 : 1;
        /* ...less than 10 altogether... */
    };
    unsigned all;
} output_flags_t;
```

(Note: unnamed `struct`/`union` members were added in C11, although some compilers supported them before standardization.)

And the output code looks like:

```
output_flags_t output_flags = {0};
output_flags.f3 = 1;
printf("... %u\n", output_flags.all);
```

On my system, the above prints:

```
... 4
```

but the output is implementation dependent and the value of `output_flags.all` might be a trap representation (see below).

Regarding the use of a `union` for type punning, this is specifically allowed in the C standard, although the punned value might be a trap representation:

C17 6.5.2.3

> 3. A postfix expression followed by the `.` operator and an identifier designates a member of a structure or union object. The value is that of the named member, <sup>97)</sup> and is an lvalue if the first expression is an lvalue. If the first expression has qualified type, the result has the so-qualified version of the type of the designated member.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>97)</sup> If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted as an object representation in the new type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called “type punning”). This might be a trap representation.

Comment: `gcc` implementation is well defined

Comment: But "cleaner" means: "for gcc" (only); it's still assuming that the size of `unsigned` and the bitset is the same, right?

Comment: @0___________ You are talking about the bit order? Maybe add a reference!

Comment: Well, personally I think using a `union` to write one type, then reading another isn't actually clear design, but it hides the ugly bits from the compiler.

Comment: @0___________ "implementation defined" means just that: the implementation of a compiler defines the behavior. Whether this is documented or not, doesn't matter. Your code is not generally portable.

Comment: @U.Windl The size and alignment of the `struct` containing the bit-field members will be implementation-defined, but the size and alignment of the `union` will be at least that of the `unsigned int` member.

Comment: @U.Windl By "cleaner" I mean cleaner than type punning via strict aliasing rule breaking pointers.

Comment: @U.Windl Although it is better to avoid bit-fields altogether for portability if their layout needs to match something external to the code.

Answer (score -1):

It is not. Use union instead:

```
typedef union {
    struct {
        unsigned f1 : 1;
        unsigned f2 : 1;
        unsigned f3 : 1;
/* ...less than 10 alltogether... */
    }
    unsigned raw;
} output_flags_t;
```

Comment: What is "it" referring to?